# Should all interactions go to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf

So basically I guess I know the role of MVVM, but correct me if I am wrong

View: Basically it whats the users sees + it takes user interaction

Also View: It shouldn't know what the model is ... but it must know what is the ViewModel is

ViewModel: its the Glue code that does the binding + code transformation + Interactions(not all for me)

Also ViewModel: It doesn't know what is the view ... it only knows how to expose the Model data and take interactions results to the Model

So here are some practical questions:

If you have a pdf program ... where do you put the logic of zooming in and out, in the View or in the ViewModel? I know interactions should go to ViewModel, but that specific interaction my model will not care about at all so why bother putting it in ViewModel ... when the ViewModel shouldn't know the view anyway

If you have color settings ... Obviously you want the user to change the color when he changes settings and that can easily be done by XAML only ... but also you want to save that interaction but you may want to save it with all settings just before closing the application ... so why bother putting the code of changing color setting in ViewModel when it can be done in View with XAML using eventTrigger ... and then before close capture all settings and save it?

I just want to confirm if my logic is right ... should I keep UI interaction in the View instead of ViewModel if the Model won't care about it ... or should I always put it in ViewModel no matter what happens?

Comment: "ViewModel: its the Glue code" - that's not all it is; it's also a *model* (representation) of the view, that's why it's called view model. It represents abstractly the dynamic aspects of the view, but without the controls used to render things on screen (paraphrasing Martin Fowler here). So the logic (or component) that does the actual zooming (the rendering of it) would go into the view, but the data that stores the zoom level, position of the document within the zoom box, etc., would go into the ViewModel, and the view (or the zoom component) would bind to that data.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... if you wrote that as an answer I would vote it.